# insert and select in one query default values

Tags: oracle

I use following query to insert a new row:

```
insert into table1 (c1, c2, c3) (select c1, c2, c3 from table2 where some_condition)
```

This works finely if there is a row in table2 that satisfies `some_condition`. But if there are no rows, nothing is inserted.

Are there any way to specify default values to insert if select returns empty result set? I want to do that in one sql query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't very pretty, but it does what you want, You'd need to test with your environment to see if it performs well enough

```
SQL> drop table so_tgt;

Table dropped.

SQL> 
SQL> create table so_src (
  2   c1 varchar2(6)
  3  ,c2 varchar2(6)
  4  ,c3 varchar2(6)
  5  );

Table created.

SQL> 
SQL> insert into so_src values ( 'foo','bar','moo' );

1 row created.

SQL> 
SQL> create table so_tgt as select * from so_src where 1 = 0;

Table created.

SQL> 
SQL> /* Test for existing row insert */
SQL> insert into so_tgt
  2  with x as ( select s.*, 1 as r
  3          from so_src s
  4          where c1='foo'
  5          union
  6          select 'x','y','z',0 as r /* DEFAULT VALUES */
  7          from dual )
  8  select c1,c2,c3
  9  from x
 10  where r = ( select max(r) from x ) ;

1 row created.

SQL> 
SQL> select * from so_tgt;

C1     C2     C3
------ ------ ------
foo    bar    moo

SQL> truncate table so_tgt;

Table truncated.

SQL> 
SQL> /* Test for default row insert */
SQL> insert into so_tgt
  2  with x as ( select s.*, 1 as r
  3          from so_src s
  4          where c1='far'
  5          union
  6          select 'x','y','z',0 as r /* DEFAULT VALUES */
  7          from dual )
  8  select c1,c2,c3
  9  from x
 10  where r = ( select max(r) from x ) ;

1 row created.

SQL> 
SQL> select * from so_tgt;

C1     C2     C3
------ ------ ------
x      y      z

SQL> truncate table so_tgt ;

Table truncated.
```

Answer (score 1):

The quick and dirty way, if you don't mind repeating `some_condition` and where `some_condition` doesn't depend on the values in table2 is:

```
insert into table1 (c1,c2,c3)
select c1, c2, c3 from table2 where some_condition
union select defaultvalue1, defaultvalue2, defaultvalue3 from dual where not (some_condition)
```

If `some_condition` *does* depend on values in table2, then you can do (untested):

```
   insert into table1 (c1,c2,c3)
   select nvl(t2.c1, defaultvalue1), nvl(t2.c2, defaultvalue2), nvl(t2.c2, defaultvalue3)
   from dual left join (select c1,c2,c3 from table2 where some_condition) t2
   on 1 = 1
```

If I'm right, this query will always return at least one row, but if no rows showed up on the right side, then the t2 values will all be returned as null and so the `nvl` can be used to provide your default values.

**Edit**: Small caveat. This assumes that the values returned from table2 will not be null or that if they are, you want the default values.